# Is there a way to create a Zend_Controller_Router that matches /text but not /text/?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to match URLs without a trailing slash to one router and want those with the trailing slash behave the normal way. I've tried:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':redirectid',
            array(
                'redirectid'    =>  false,
                'controller'    =>  'redirect',
                'action'    =>  'redirect'
            ),
            array('redirectid' => '[a-z0-9]*')
        );
```

and

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            '([a-z0-9]*)',
            array(
                'controller' => 'redirect',
                'action'     => 'redirect'
            )
        );
```

and both behave exactly how I want for urls without trailing slash, yet they still match for urls with a trailing slash, too. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:**
I would highly suggest against making http://somesite.com/page and http://somesite.com/page/ being different pages- it will become confusing for you and for your visitors.

**If you're truly dedicated to this plan**
you can create your own router you can that handles this by creating your own match() and assemble() functions that don't `trim()` the path based on trailing slashes.

```
class My_Route_Redirector implements Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Interface {
   protected $_defaults;

   public static function getInstance(Zend_Config $config) {
     $defs = ($config->defaults instanceof Zend_Config) ? $config->defaults->toArray() : array();
     return new self($defs);
   }

   public function __construct($defaults=array()) {
     $this->_defaults = $defaults;
   }

   public function match($path, $partial = false) {
     if (preg_match("#^/?([a-z0-9]+)$#i", $path, $matches)) {
       // this is just an idea but what about if you had this test
       // $matches[1] versus the database of redirectors?  and only return true
       // when it found a valid redirector?

       return array('redirectid' => $matches[1]) + $this->_defaults;
     } else {
       return false;
     }
   }

    public function assemble($data = array(), $reset = false, $encode = false, $partial = false)
    {
      if (!isset($data['redirectid'])) return '';
      return $data['redirectid'];
    }
}
```

That was air coded so it may have a bug or two to work out - it should work like this:

```
$route = new My_Route_Redirector(
                array(
                        'controller' => 'redirect',
                        'action'     => 'redirect'
                )
        );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working fine, except that the $path still includes the beginning /, "#^/([a-z0-9]+)$#i" makes it work. I actually do fight with myself over the do it/don't it - it's for a tinyurl-like redirector and I didn't just want to match everything, so I can still have /admin/ or /stats/ etc. Having specific routes for those might be preferable, I'll have to sleep over that one.

Comment: You could just fall down to /admin/index/ for your basic :controller/:action route right?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing - basically I route those routes that I need with just one parameter (/admin/) with a static route, those with more than one (/admin/options/) will use the adminController anyway.

Comment: I just had an idea looking at this again - you could have this custom route only return the values when it finds something that matches against your DB rows -  It could even set the "redirectTo" param.  Then /admin would still be a "default" route - and you wouldn't need special case statics.

Comment: Hm, I like that idea - even though it would take out all the logic out of the redirectController, after all, if I query the db anyway, I could just redirect right there in the router.